# odoo unit testing for customized project module

Tags: unit-testing, odoo

I am writing unit tests for custom addon developed on top of project (project.task) module which is also heavily customized. While writing unit test cases, its painful to create project.task model objects which involves creating multiple sub class objects before creating the actual task model object. This process is painful as each sub class object in turn has many fields. While creating a task from the user interface is lot easier as system creates all the sub class objects with necessary fields. Is there a better way of creating the necessary dummy objects for the sake of unit testing?

Comment: why can't you use the default odoo demo for the task and add your custom field data into it. it will reduce your half of the code. When we write the unit test it is not obvious we are creating any object. you can use the already created demo data from the odoo. (take any odoo reference)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do this:

- Use default_get() function: this set default data for some fields (with default parameter)
- Use name_create() function: to create a record with just name.

But you must remember those 2 function are only available when you have them in your model